# My iOS App is not being recognized by Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

I am really tired of Game Center, it's not working at all!

Everything is done correctly (Leaderboard, BundleID, Description...) and I am sure 100% that nothing is missing

here.

No login, leaderoard is not showing... nothing is working.

Please help me!

Need to fix it to finish the multiplayer part of the game.

I've tested in ipod with iOS6, iPad with iOS7, simulators iOS 6,7,8

Check the screenshot.

If there is no way to fix it, can someone give me an alternative to gameCenter please?

[image]

Thank you

**Update**

Game Center is Enabled:

[image]

And Leaderboard:

[image]

And Enabled Here:

[image]

Same BundleID & version:

[image]

App ID in developer account (ID & BundleID are the same):

[image]

Provisioning profile:

[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting screenshots of what you have done in iTunesConnect?

Comment: Thank you for responding, see the edit

Comment: possible duplicate of ["This game is not recognized by Game Center" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616426/this-game-is-not-recognized-by-game-center-error)

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. And it worked last night normally. My Game logged in as sandbox successfully 2 times, then never worked. There's no problem with the implementation and the code. I think the problem could be in iOS7 or in the server. and the solution in your possible duplicate post has a proken link